# -w doesn't exist. Create it?

Tags: git, git-bash

So I'm trying to learn how to use git right now and am following the Udacity git tutorial. After I add to the staging area and commit, my text editor (N++) opens up and I get this message:

```
C:\Users\myUserName\version-control\reflections\\-w doesn't exist. Create it?
```

If I click "Yes", it create the -w file and asks me to fill out my commit message and everything works fine, except that I get a -w file in my directory.

If I click "No", everything works fine without creating the -w file.

Can anyone help me fix this? I feel like I might have forgotten a quote or something like that when setting up the workspace.

These are the commands I ran (might have mistyped something):

```
git config --global core.editor "'C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' -n -w"
git config --global push.default upstream
git config --global merge.conflictstyle diff3
```

Comment: `-w` is supposed to be a switch, not a file name.

Comment: I'd rather (1) learn in a way that doesn't have dependencies on environment, e.g. **git bash**. Or (2), choose a well designed third party tool that ensures you focusing on git, rather than configure your environment, e.g. **sourcetree**. Personally I use git bash in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

Oops. Turns out -n and -w are for sublime. This works for Notepad++:

"'C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin"